Email address empty when trying to read it out at the back end
I'm trying to log in using a custom HTML template via sendgrid which will contain the OTP code. But when I verify the code I see that "Username" property is empty in the back end. And it must be going wrong somewhere in my custom policy where the Username should be passed on:
<TrustFrameworkPolicy xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/online/cpim/schemas/2013/06" 
  PolicySchemaVersion="0.3.0.0" 
  TenantId="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.onmicrosoft.com" 
  PolicyId="B2C_1A_DisplayControl_sendgrid_Extensions" 
  PublicPolicyUri="http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_DisplayControl_sendgrid_Extensions">
  <BasePolicy>
    <TenantId>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.onmicrosoft.com</TenantId>
    <PolicyId>B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkExtensions</PolicyId>
  </BasePolicy>
  <BuildingBlocks>
    <ClaimsSchema>
      <ClaimType Id="otp">
        <DisplayName>Secondary One-time password</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
      </ClaimType>
      <ClaimType Id="emailRequestBody">
        <DisplayName>SendGrid request body</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
      </ClaimType>
      <ClaimType Id="verificationCode">
        <DisplayName>Secondary Verification Code</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
        <UserHelpText>Enter your email verification code</UserHelpText>
        <UserInputType>TextBox</UserInputType>
      </ClaimType>
      <ClaimType Id="subject">
        <DisplayName>Email subject</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
      </ClaimType>
      <ClaimType Id="message">
        <DisplayName>Email message</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
      </ClaimType>
      <ClaimType Id="codeIntro">
        <DisplayName>Email code introduction</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
      </ClaimType>
      <ClaimType Id="signature">
        <DisplayName>Email signature</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
      </ClaimType>
    </ClaimsSchema>
    <ClaimsTransformations>
      <ClaimsTransformation Id="GetLocalizedStringsForEmail" TransformationMethod="GetLocalizedStringsTransformation">
        <OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="subject" TransformationClaimType="email_subject" />
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="message" TransformationClaimType="email_message" />
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="codeIntro" TransformationClaimType="email_code" />
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signature" TransformationClaimType="email_signature" />
        </OutputClaims>
      </ClaimsTransformation>
      <ClaimsTransformation Id="GenerateEmailRequestBody" TransformationMethod="GenerateJson">
        <InputClaims>
          <!-- needed claims depend on the email template used -->
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" TransformationClaimType="personalizations.0.to.0.email" />
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="otp" TransformationClaimType="personalizations.0.dynamic_template_data.otp" />

        </InputClaims>
        <InputParameters>
          <InputParameter Id="template_id" DataType="string" Value="d-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" />
          <InputParameter Id="from.email" DataType="string" Value="info@XXXXXXXXX.com" />
        </InputParameters>
        <OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="emailRequestBody" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
        </OutputClaims>
      </ClaimsTransformation>
      <ClaimsTransformation Id="CopySignInToEmailClaim" TransformationMethod="CopyClaim">
        <InputClaims>
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim"/>
        </InputClaims>
        <OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim"/>
        </OutputClaims>
      </ClaimsTransformation>
    </ClaimsTransformations>
    <ContentDefinitions>
      <ContentDefinition Id="api.localaccountsignup">
        <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:selfasserted:2.1.0</DataUri>
        <LocalizedResourcesReferences MergeBehavior="Prepend">
          <LocalizedResourcesReference Language="en" LocalizedResourcesReferenceId="api.custom-email.en" />
          <LocalizedResourcesReference Language="es" LocalizedResourcesReferenceId="api.custom-email.es" />
        </LocalizedResourcesReferences>
      </ContentDefinition>
      <ContentDefinition Id="api.localaccountpasswordreset">
        <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:selfasserted:2.1.0</DataUri>
        <LocalizedResourcesReferences MergeBehavior="Prepend">
          <LocalizedResourcesReference Language="en" LocalizedResourcesReferenceId="api.custom-email.en" />
          <LocalizedResourcesReference Language="es" LocalizedResourcesReferenceId="api.custom-email.es" />
        </LocalizedResourcesReferences>
      </ContentDefinition>
    </ContentDefinitions>
    
    <DisplayControls>
      <DisplayControl Id="emailVerificationControl" UserInterfaceControlType="VerificationControl">
        <!-- input claim to prepopulated the email claim in MFA section -->
        <InputClaims>
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email"/>
        </InputClaims>
        <DisplayClaims>
          <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" Required="true" />
          <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="verificationCode" ControlClaimType="VerificationCode" Required="true" />
        </DisplayClaims>
        <OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
        </OutputClaims>
        <Actions>
          <Action Id="SendCode">
            <ValidationClaimsExchange>
              <ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile TechnicalProfileReferenceId="GenerateOtp" />
              <ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SendOtp" />
            </ValidationClaimsExchange>
          </Action>
          <Action Id="VerifyCode">
            <ValidationClaimsExchange>
              <ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile TechnicalProfileReferenceId="VerifyOtp" />
            </ValidationClaimsExchange>
          </Action>
        </Actions>
      </DisplayControl>
      <DisplayControl Id="emailVerificationSSPRControl" UserInterfaceControlType="VerificationControl">
        <InputClaims>
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" DefaultValue="{OIDC:LoginHint}" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
        </InputClaims>
        <DisplayClaims>
          <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" Required="true" />
          <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="verificationCode" ControlClaimType="VerificationCode" Required="true" />
        </DisplayClaims>
        <OutputClaims></OutputClaims>
        <Actions>
          <Action Id="SendCode">
            <ValidationClaimsExchange>
              <ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-CheckEmailAddressExists" />
              <ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile TechnicalProfileReferenceId="GenerateOtp" />
              <ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SendOtp">
                <Preconditions>
                  <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
                    <Value>objectId</Value>
                    <Action>SkipThisValidationTechnicalProfile</Action>
                  </Precondition>
                </Preconditions>
              </ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile>
            </ValidationClaimsExchange>
          </Action>
          <Action Id="VerifyCode">
            <ValidationClaimsExchange>
              <ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile TechnicalProfileReferenceId="VerifyOtp" />
            </ValidationClaimsExchange>
          </Action>
        </Actions>
      </DisplayControl>
    </DisplayControls>
  </BuildingBlocks>
  <ClaimsProviders>
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>One time password technical profiles</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="GenerateOtp">
          <DisplayName>Generate one time password</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.OneTimePasswordProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="Operation">GenerateCode</Item>
            <Item Key="CodeExpirationInSeconds">60</Item>
            <Item Key="CodeLength">6</Item>
            <Item Key="CharacterSet">0-9</Item>
            <Item Key="ReuseSameCode">true</Item>
            <Item Key="NumRetryAttempts">2</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="identifier" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="otp" PartnerClaimType="otpGenerated" />
          </OutputClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="VerifyOtp">
          <DisplayName>Verify one time password</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.OneTimePasswordProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="Operation">VerifyCode</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="identifier" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="verificationCode" PartnerClaimType="otpToVerify" />
          </InputClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>RestfulProvider</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="SendOtp">
          <DisplayName>Use SendGrid's email API to send the code the the user</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="ServiceUrl">https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send</Item>
            <Item Key="AuthenticationType">Bearer</Item>
            <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Body</Item>
            <Item Key="ClaimUsedForRequestPayload">emailRequestBody</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <CryptographicKeys>
            <Key Id="BearerAuthenticationToken" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_SendGridSecret" />
          </CryptographicKeys>
          <InputClaimsTransformations>
            <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="GenerateEmailRequestBody" />
          </InputClaimsTransformations>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="emailRequestBody" />
          </InputClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Local Account</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail">
          <InputClaimsTransformations>
            <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="GetLocalizedStringsForEmail" />
          </InputClaimsTransformations>
          <DisplayClaims>
            <DisplayClaim DisplayControlReferenceId="emailVerificationControl" />
            <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" Required="true" />
            <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" Required="true" />
            <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" Required="true" />
            <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" Required="true" />
            <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="reenterPassword" Required="true" />
          </DisplayClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-CheckEmailAddressExists">
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="Operation">Read</Item>
            <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">false</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.emailAddress" Required="true"/>
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId"/>
          </OutputClaims>
          <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common"/>
        </TechnicalProfile>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email">
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName"/>
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName"/>
          </OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaimsTransformations>
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CopySignInToEmailClaim"/>
          </OutputClaimsTransformations>
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Reset Password</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingEmailAddress">
          <InputClaimsTransformations>
            <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="GetLocalizedStringsForEmail" />
          </InputClaimsTransformations>
          <DisplayClaims>
            <DisplayClaim DisplayControlReferenceId="emailVerificationSSPRControl"/>
          </DisplayClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
    <ClaimsProvider>
    <DisplayName>MFA</DisplayName>
    <TechnicalProfiles>
      <TechnicalProfile Id="Authenticate2Factor">
        <DisplayName>Verify Email</DisplayName>
        <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
        <Metadata>
          <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountpasswordreset</Item>
        </Metadata>
        <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
        <DisplayClaims>
          <DisplayClaim DisplayControlReferenceId="emailVerificationControl" />
        </DisplayClaims>
      </TechnicalProfile>
    </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
  </ClaimsProviders>
  <UserJourneys>
    <UserJourney Id="SignUpOrSignInV2">
      <OrchestrationSteps>
        <!-- Existing CombinedSignInAndSignUp Step -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
          <ClaimsProviderSelections>
            <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
          </ClaimsProviderSelections>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <!-- Step 2: Registration Step if user is not registered -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
              <Value>email</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="MFA-Exchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="Authenticate2Factor" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <!-- Step 7: Issue Token -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
      </OrchestrationSteps>
      <ClientDefinition ReferenceId="DefaultWeb" />
    </UserJourney>
  </UserJourneys>
</TrustFrameworkPolicy>

What am I doing wrong?

When implementing a custom email verification system using SendGrid, ensure that the email address claim is correctly collected and passed through the various technical profiles. check Claims Transformation,Display Control, Technical Profiles, Claims Schema.

Email address is passed through all profiles.

Add this as part of your RP:

<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" PartnerClaimType="Username" />

No more claims declaration is needed for this as it's part of JWT. It's been tested and here is a cropped JWT claims where we could see the Username claim as a copy of signInName as follows.

{"auth_time":1733398231,"email":"abc@xyz.com","iat":1733398231,"name":"abc@xyz.com","nonce":"defaultNonce","Username":"abc@xyz.com"}

Chaining conversation is added here for our reference

Hi bro, just tried that :  and removed this from RP:  and the username is still empty when i check the jwt object in the backend.

Ah never mind, had to change the object on client side. Username is a level deeper in the object.
